# Two Apple IDs, can I use both on same device?

Tags: iphone

When I got my new iPhone six, I made a new Apple ID, not realizing that I wouldn't be able to get my music from my previous Apple ID. I redeemed a $15 iTunes card on my new Apple ID, and I am now unsure whether or not using it and downloading music onto my phone will erase the data from the other Apple ID. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "Family Sharing" Function in iTunes and add the original Apple-ID as a Family member, who can use your Music. See further explanations for Family Sharing here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201060